Can I view SQL Server encryption certificate remotely
The SQL Server connection encryption certificate expired on Friday. I don't have console access to the SQL Server. I sent instructions to a sysadmin on how to install the new cert through SQL Server Config Mgr. He told me that he did all the steps and rebooted the server, but here it is Monday morning, and I'm getting the certificate error.
I'm able to connect with SSMS by selecting "Trust the Server Certificate" but that's not an option for all of the other analysts & scheduled processes with saved connections. I need to verify the certificate that's installed without access to the server. Is there a way with TSQL or SSMS to view the certificate details? I'm not finding anything.
BTW, to forestall incorrect answers, select * from sys.certificates shows database certificates, not the server's encrypted connection certificate.

|He told me that he did all the steps` have them create screen shots next time to document the installation. Microsoft has a tool that can do this (psr). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/settings/how-to-use-problem-steps-recorder

use openssl
openssl s_client -connect <hostname>:<port> -showcerts

